# HTML DOM Position Refresh Rate

Tags: javascript, css, dom, html

Let say I got this:

```
aFunction = function(){
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    div.style.top = '0px';
    div.style.top = '50px';
    div.style.top = '100px';
    anotherFunction();
}
```

If I call the function `aFunction`, will the div ever be displayed in the position 50px? Or will it simply go from 0px to 100px? (I'm concern about performance.)

Also, when does the position change occur exactly?

Does it happen immediately after the assignment,

Or at the end of `aFunction`

Or at the end of `anotherFunction()`

Or when the browser is idle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4th and 5th lines will be ignored and will *never* take effect, simply because the 6th line overrides those *immediately*. The position change will also be noted (as in you can `alert(div.style.top)` and it will return the last assigned value) *immediately*, tho it's *rendered* when the browser is idle. After the 2nd line goes the 3rd line goes the 4th line goes the 5th (goes the 6th), simple as that, tho the rendering is done separately.

Answer (score 0):

All of those style changes will be picked up by the browser and the DOM will be start to be re-flowed.  The changes will happen so quickly though that the browser will never get the chance to finish composition and repainting.  Unless you are running on hardware that will take more than 16ms to update the CSSOM, which should be impossible to find.

If you did this, then the reflow will only happen once, when the fragment is added to the DOM.

```
aFunction = function(){
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.style.top = '0px';
  div.style.top = '50px';
  div.style.top = '100px';

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

I ran this code in Chrome, and I only get the rendering of the last color.  I would have expected to see blue background for 10 seconds, but I never do.

```
div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){}
div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
```